# Blazor ~ How to call from component's method a parents method with argument?

Tags: blazor

At a Blazor component I need to pass data to the parent (a page).
At the page it must call a method (or event) because a immediately reaction is needed.
I can't find a example or manual for this behaviour.

Does anybody has a example or a link for that case?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that `EventCallback` is what you are looking for:

**Page** :

```
<Comp CallToAction="(data)=>ProcessData(data)"></Comp>
<div>Data from component: @dataFromComponent </div>

@code {
string dataFromComponent = "";

void ProcessData(string data)
{
dataFromComponent = data;
}
}
```

**Component** :

```
<button @onclick=ClickMethod>Click me</button>

@code{
    async Task ClickMethod()
    {
       await  CallToAction.InvokeAsync(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
    [Parameter]public EventCallback<string> CallToAction {get;set;}
}
```

[Online demo](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/cmuAlhFt30w0C0t639)